# Notepad++ Capitalize Every First Letter of Every Word

Tags: regex, notepad++

Input: `"notepad++ capitalize every first letter of every word"`

Output: `"Notepad++ Capitalize Every First Letter Of Every Word"`

I have been attempting to capitalize the first letter of every word using `ctr+F` and `regex`.

So far I have been attempting to use find:`\b(.)` or `\<(.)` with replace:`\u\1` but this results in all of my letters being capitalized.

I have made due with [`^(.)` & `\u\1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529148/notepad-capitalize-first-letter-by-shortcut) followed by `\s\b(.)` & `\u\1`.

However, this seems silly to me as there are many posts talking about using the start of word boundaries. I am just having difficulty making them work. Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: There is no way to do that in N++ unless you use some third party plugin. Nor with regex

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Background

According to Notepad++ specification (see [*Substitutions*](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) section), there are three operators that can be useful when turning substrings uppercase:

> `\u`
>   Causes next character to output in uppercase
>   `\U`
>   Causes next characters to be output in uppercase, until a `\E` is found.
>   `\E`
>   Puts an end to forced case mode initiated by `\L` or `\U`.

Thus, you can either **match a substring and turn its first character uppercase with `\u`** to capitalize it, or **match a character and use `\U`/`\E`**.

**Note that Unicode characters won't be turned uppercase, only ASCII letters are affected.**

---

## BOW (Beginning of Word) Bug in Notepad++

Note that currently (in Notepad++ v.6.8.8) the beginning of word does not work for some reason. A common solution that works with most engines (use it in Sublime Text and it will match) does not work:

```
\b(\w)
```

This regex matches all word characters irrespective of their position in the string.

**I logged a bug [*Word boundary issue with a generic subpattern next to it #1404*](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1404)**.

---

## Solution #1 (for the current Notepad++ v.6.8.8)

The **first solution** can be using the `\w+` and replace with `\u$0` (no need using any capturing groups). Though this does not mean we only match the characters at the beginning of a word, the pattern will just match chunks of word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` + all Unicode letters/digits) and will turn the first character uppercase.

---

## Solution #2 (for the current Notepad++ v.6.8.8)

The **second solution** can be implemented with special boundaries defined with *lookbehinds*:

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\W))\w
```

And replace with `\U$0\E`.

The regex `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\W))\w` matches an alphanumeric only at the beginning of a line (`(?<=^)`) or after a non-word character (`(?<=\W)`).

The replacement - `\U$0\E` - contains a `\U` flag that starts turning letters uppercase and `\E` is a flag that tells Notepad++ to stop converting case.

---

**Edge case**

In case you have hyphenated words, like `well-known`, and you only want the first part to be capitalized, you can use `[\w-]+` with `\u$0` replacement. It will also keep strings like `-v` or `--help` intact.

Comment: This was much more complicated than I expected. Thanks

Comment: If I could only upvote this over 200 times (The number of items that I needed to convert). Saved me hours of editing. Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI: This only works with ASCII letters, Cyrillic etc. letters cannot be changed using the case swapping operators in Notepad++.

Answer (score 26):

A simpler regex that worked for me:

Find: `(\w+)`

Replace: `\u$0`

Answer (score 12):

There is a shortcut available in Notepad++ v7.3.2 to capitalize every first letter of every word.

ALT + U

Not sure about prior versions.

Comment: It seems to work for selected text only. Also, `Ctrl+Alt+U` changes the selected text to sentence case.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks, brother.
And `CTRL+U` do the exact opposite. `i-e changes "InitCap" to "initcap"`

Answer (score 6):

Uppercase The First Letter Of Every Word:
Use the shortcut: Alt + U

lowercase the first letter of every word:
Use the shortcut: Clt + U

Shortcut working in version 7.6.3

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved something similar by recording a macro that uses the following replacement.

```
Find what:    ([a-z])+
Replace with: \u$0\E

Tick 'In selection'
```

---

This is the resulting macro that I extracted from `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`.

```
<Macro name="Title Case" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="([A-Z])" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\L$0" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="898" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="([a-z])+" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\u$0\E" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="898" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

---

Extra: you can add this to your right-click context menu (`contextMenu.xml`) using:

```
<Item MenuEntryName="Macro" MenuItemName="Title Case" />
```