# Regular Expression - Add a character before/after each word

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using **Notepad++** and **replace** function, I tried to add a symbol "**+**" or "**[**" before each word of my list.

Example of list :

- blue car
- red car big
- red car small
- green car big
- green car small

I'm looking for the following result :

- +blue +car
- +red +car +small
- +red +car +big
- .. etc

I know how to add a character befor each line... but I cannot find the way to add it in front of **every word** without using replace "**blue**" to "**+blue**".

Comment: What does this have to do with `php`?

Comment: what has php to do in this ? (giving my understanding of your problem :replacing  words using notepad RegExp)

Comment: Try `\b\w+\b` replacing with `+$&`

Comment: Please check which answer works best for you and consider accepting an answer. If you find an answer helpful, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cross platform solution should be

*Search*: `\b\w+\b` (or `\b[[:alpha:]]+\b`)
*Replace*: `+$&`

**Search pattern details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (if `[[:alpha:]]+` is used, 1+ letters)
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary

*Replacement details*: `+` is a literal plus, and `$&` is the backreference to the whole match.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation... Still have some work to manage the regex !

Comment: You mean "learn" :) ? Note that most of the online regex testers should be trusted to a certain degree since they do not usually support the NPP way of handling regex. Check [Boost regex syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html), and always test in Notepad++.

Comment: Yes learning is the key ! I find myself using regex more and more to work with big words list and tables. But I lack of time to deepen all subjects. Thx again for help !

Answer (score 2):

(see screenshot below)

- open the Find/Replace dialog (`Ctrt`+`H`)
- in the `Find` input, enter this regex: `(\b\w)` which means "word boundary followed by a letter"
- in the `Replace with` input, enter this replacement: `+\1` which means "put a `+` sign followed by whatever was matched between the regex parenthesis"
- click `Show advanced options` checkbox
- click `Search with regular expressions` radio button
- then hit `Replace` button as many times as you want, or use `Replace all` for once

[image]

EDIT: for Windows is pretty much the same (see the find/replace dialog http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/image_1AFC2B61.png) the Regular Expression option is at the bottom left

Comment: yes I tried it, and works for me. See screenshot. Did you made all the regex options the same as displayed dialog?

Comment: OK, the `\b` doesn't seem to work right in Windows NPP.

Comment: added Windows answer as well, but screenshot is taken from the web, so options are not marked properly

Comment: I tested on Windows. Using `red car small` replace `(\b\w)` with `+\1` yields: `+r+e+d +c+a+r +s+m+a+l+l`

Comment: not sure why, but in that case, change it to `(\b\w+)` and should sort it out

Comment: No, in Windows NPP, `\b\w` does not work, see [Notepad++ Capitalize Every First Letter of Every Word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952353/notepad-capitalize-every-first-letter-of-every-word/31953204#31953204).

Comment: That's what i needed... thank you ! And sorry for late answer.