# Using found text in replace text

Tags: replace, notepad++

I want to add a new line before a date and the dates change so I use . to match 28/06/2023 -> ../../2023.
I would like to still get \n28/06/2023 in the end result.

So my question is if you in Notepad++ can use the found text in the replacement text when using regex?
Or if it is possible **not** to replace and just add a new line before the date?

[image: Replace]

Comment: Yes, you can use regex in notepad++ for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capture group:

- Find what: `\d\d/\d\d/2023`
- Replace with: `\n$0`

Where `$0` contains the whole match.

Another way is to use lookahead:

- Find what: `(?=\d\d/\d\d/2023)`
- Replace with: `\n`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [this website](https://www.keycdn.com/support/regex-cheat-sheet) and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40614597/11968910):

I believe what you're looking for would be:

*Search:* `../../2023`

*Replace:* `\n$&`

Let me know if this works :)